# sed - break line after insert text on the first line of the file in OSX

Tags: macos, sed

I cannot break a line after inserting some text on the first line of the file.

```
find . -type f -path '*/browser/components/*/*.react.js' -exec sed -i "" '1 i\
import { logRender } from "../../common/lib/logger";/\n/g' {} +
```

it returns:

```
import { logRender } from "../../common/lib/logger";/n/gimport Component from 'react-pure-render/component';
```

instead of:

```
import { logRender } from "../../common/lib/logger";
import Component from 'react-pure-render/component';
```

Anyone has the same experience? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a newline inside the single quotes. So, starting with `file.txt` like this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

You can do:

```
sed '1 i\
hello
' file.txt
```

and get this:

```
hello
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Comment: Never thought this way, it works like a charms, thanks man :D

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, for anything else you should be using awk:

```
find . -type f -path '*/browser/components/*/*.react.js' -exec awk -i inplace 'FNR==1{print "import { logRender } from \"../../common/lib/logger\""}1' {} +
```

The above uses GNU awk for "inplace" editing.